# Interbase .NET entity framework provider

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, interbase

I'd like to use the entity framework for my next project and i'm having some issues finding a .NET interbase driver that supports the entity framework.  I attempted to install the Firebird drivers from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/ but keep running into a vague error when trying to establish a connnection through the Entity Data Model wizard, Error is as follows

```
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"
```

If i had to guess, the issue lies with the fact that i'm trying to use an firebird driver to connect to an interbase database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, there is no EF provider for IB. For the time being, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify your Interbase version. Believe me when I say that *really matters*, because Interbase has been around for a while.

For newer versions, there's already a question here at SO: [Best way to connect to Interbase 7.1 using .NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219684/best-way-to-connect-to-interbase-7-1-using-net-c).

For older versions, you should consider moving to Firebird. Firebird .NET provider will work well then.

Comment: Interbase 2007 is the current version, and i'm looking for something that specifically supports the .NET entity framework.  We already have in place ODBC drivers for ADO transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the Firebird .NET driver only for Firebird.

Maybe you can take a look at [IBProvider](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/) who make oledb driver for Interbase and Firebird.

Comment: Does IBProvider support EF though?

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer to an old question, but nevertheless noteworthy to mention I believe:

As far as I currently know, there is no support (yet, but it is coming for the near future I believe) for connecting Interbase database with EF. However, it should be possible to write your own provider based upon the guidelines from EF which can be found [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6). I've come across the exact same issue, which I solved by writing a driver for usage with Interbase XE7 and EF 6 (6.1.2).

To get started, you might want to have a look at the FireBird provider (which is open source) and is already working with EF. If you study the provided code, you might have a good trigger to write your own Interbase provider for EF. The link to FireBirds EF .NET Provider can be found [here](https://github.com/cincuranet/NETProvider)

**As a tip:**
You need to look at the SQL generator and manifests within the Firebird driver and compare this with the the Interbase SQL grammar. The mappings really differ, but it is just about some small details. When compiling the Firebird driver with the conditional compilation symbols GDS32, the Firebird driver will look and load the gds32.dll provided by Interbase.

Comment: I have gone through the Firebird EF6 provider, in the code I found SSDL and MSL files as well. As I know those files are generated by the conceptual model / EDMX. Can you explain why SSDL and MSL files has to be mapped with the Interbase databse.